# Windows 10 - easier connection to Bluetooth device?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, user-interface

In Windows 10, is there a way to connect to a specific Bluetooth device without opening the Bluetooth CP?

On my Mac, the Bluetooth menu in the menu bar lists all know BT-devices so I only need one click to list all devices and a second click to connect to a specific device. Can I set up Windows 10, maybe with third party software, in a similar way? E.g., right click on the BT-icon in the tray or in the message center.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily just press WIN + K

Comment: Can you explain how this will help to connect to a specific device? Thanks!